# Erdős–Rado theorem generalisation for infinitely many colours

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I'll ask my question and then explain the background.  Thanks in advance.

**Question:** Is it the case that
$$
\beth_{\omega}\rightarrow (\beth_{\omega})_{{\aleph_{0}}}^{n}
$$
for finite $n$?  If not, what more generally can be said about cardinals $\kappa$ such that
$$
\kappa\rightarrow (\kappa)_{{\aleph_{0}}}^{n}
$$
holds, for finite $n$?

**Background:**

Wikipedia [succinctly states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_combinatorics) the Erdős–Rado theorem as follows:
$$
\beth_{n}^{+}\rightarrow (\aleph_{1})_{{\aleph_{0}}}^{{n+1}}
$$
*In words and paraphrasing slightly this says: if we countably colour the $n{+}1$-size subsets of a set $X$ of cardinality greater than $\beth_{n}$, then there exists a homogeneous subset of uncountable cardinality.*

Then it [re-states a more general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Rado_theorem):
$$
\exp_{n}(\kappa )^{+}\longrightarrow (\kappa^{+})_{\kappa }^{{n+1}}
$$
An $\aleph_0$-colouring is also a $\kappa$-colouring for $\kappa\geq\aleph_0$, and $\beth_\omega > \exp_n(\beth_i)$ for finite $i$, so from this it seems to me that we can derive for every finite $i$ that
$$
\beth_{\omega}\longrightarrow (\beth_i^{+})_{\aleph_0}^{{n+1}} .
$$
This suggests that we might try to take a limit as $i$ rises towards $\omega$ --- and we arrive at my question.

Advice welcome, thank you.

Comment: The answer to your first question is no, even for $n=1$, as $\beth_\omega\not\to(\beth_\omega)^1_{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: To start with, if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal such that $\kappa\to(\kappa)^2_2$, then $\kappa$ must be strongly inaccessible; and increasing the number of colours from $2$ to $\aleph_0$ makes no difference except in the case $\kappa=\aleph_0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_compact_cardinal

Comment: Thank you @bof, That nails the answer.